# What sort of damage would a buzz-saw weapon deal?

Tags: weapons, deadlands-d20

I have a Mad Scientist character in a Deadlands D20 campaign that is more or less an [expy](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Expy) of Dr. Zed from the Borderlands series and I could imagine eventually making a steam-powered Buzz Axe as one of his inventions (intended to make amputations easier, but easily weaponized). Thing is, while I can picture possible Malfunctions easily, I'm not sure what sort of damage a buzz-saw based weapon would deal in a d20 system, my experience being limited mostly to D&D 3.5. I have discussed the idea with my GM but he's stumped too.

What sort of damage or effects should buzz-saws have in a Deadlands d20? Feel free to cite Deadlands supplements or other D20 systems if those would give ideas.

Answer (score 8):

## What Can We Borrow From the [d20 Modern SRD](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/modern/smack/srdhome.html)?

> [**Chain Saw**](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/modern/smack/weapons.html): Military and police units use powered saws to cut through fences and open doors rapidly. They are sometimes pressed into service as weapons, often by people who watch too many movies.
>
> - Damage: 3d6
> - Critical: 20
> - Damage Type: Slashing
> - Range Increment: —
> - Size: Large
> - Weight: 10 lb.

### Opinion

For each smaller size, I would decrease the damage by 1d6. Since it is for surgical precision, I would also increase the threat range to 19–20.